# Reverse polarity protection with bidirectional current flow

Tags: current, reverse-polarity, bidirectional

I'm working on a reverse polarity protection circuit in order to avoid possible damage if the source (a 18650 3.7V battery) is mounted in the opposite direction.

[image: Schematic]

The circuit is straightforward; my doubts are regarding the 2 possibles states I can have:

- the battery is supplying power to the circuit (current flows out of the source)
- the battery is in charge (current flows into drain)

(It can't happen that I have both of these situations occurring simultaneously)

NB: The "BATTERY+" port refers to the output of the MOSFET that is connected to a DC/DC converter (when the battery is powering the circuit) and to a charger (when the battery is charging).

As I understand from theory, every MOSFET guarantees bidirectional current flow, as long as the Vgs is below the Vgs threshold (as stated in the datasheet: -0.72V).

Are there any possible problems with using this circuit schematic for both cases? (For example, during charging, I have a higher voltage on the drain of the MOSFET.)

Also, I was wondering if it might be a good idea to add another P-MOSFET in parallel with the existing one to reduce the length of the trace in my PCB layout:

[image: PCB]

For reference, I will charge the battery with a maximum of 400mA, and the blue trace is no more than 8cm.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually these are designed with a zener to gate just to ensure that Vgs stays within expected limits (overvoltage protection). And then you may also need a series resistor for the zener to protect that one in the reverse scenario. Should be examples elsewhere on this site. And well, obviously you'll want a good MOSFET with very low Rds(on).

Comment: Hi Lundin, thank you for the response. I've seen the example you are referring to. For lack of space, and for the specific of the MOSFET ( Vgs max= +- 8V), I decided to avoid it, because the maximum voltage I may have is +-4.2V. Is it unsafe?